# How do I increase copy activity throughput in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with multiple copy activities(23) from parquet to azure sql. I am experiencing low copy throughput (23kb/s) Is there a way to improve this?

Integration runtime is azure and not a self hosted IR.

Answer (score 0):

A Data Integration Unit (DIU) is a measure that represents the power of a single unit in Azure Data Factory and Synapse pipelines. Power is a combination of CPU, memory, and network resource allocation. DIU only applies to Azure integration runtime. DIU does not apply to self-hosted integration runtime.

More details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer said increasing the DIUs is the main way to increase the throughput of the copy activity.

You can try different DIU settings to tune the copy activity and see what performance you get. When I've done this, I've settled on the max DIU for my copy. Using twice as many DIUs cost twice as much per hour but made it twice as fast, so it wasn't more expensive.

If increasing the DIU's doesn't increase your performance, it probably has to do with settings in your "source" and "sink". What is the "source" of your parquet files? And can your azure sql sink handle all the writes?